# Should i give float to every element or to just need to give to first element?

Tags: css, xhtml

Should i give `float` to every element or to just need to give to first element ? if i want to set all element horizontally.

```
element-1-fixed-width   element-2-no-width-defined    element-3-fixed-width   element-4-fixed-width
```

or i should set `float:left` to some element and `float:right` to some element?

Comment: Can you give an example of the layout you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Could you explain a bit further your question? What exactly you want to get?

Consider use of `display: inline` or `inline-block` instead of floating.

Comment: i want to align some DIV horizontally. inline-block is not cross browser compatible

Comment: @Jitendra: yes it is. If you use spans instead of divs then it works in IE6+, Firefox 3+ and the other browsers. If you need Firefox 2 support, add "-moz-inline-box".

Answer (score 0):

You should give float to all elements if you want them to stack one next to the other ..

You might want to give `whitespace:nowrap` as well to the elements that have no width defined, to make sure they will not wrap at wrong places .. (*if that is required in your case*)